# Synchronized localstorage for android WebViews with online and offline content

Tags: android, android-webview, local-storage, offline-caching

I have an app that allows users to play games online or cache them locally. When they convert their game to cached, I don't want them to lose progress.

Prior to KitKat, you could set the localstorage dir, but I need newer phones to support this feature.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    playingField.getSettings().setDatabasePath("/data/data/" + playingField.getContext().getPackageName() + "/databases/");
}
```

I can't find a replacement method. As a result, here are the two directories:

```
root@ghost:/data/data/com.myapp.android/app_webview/Local Storage #
ls -la
total 80
drwx------ 2 u0_a165 u0_a165 4096 2017-01-06 11:51 .
drwxrwx--x 4 u0_a165 u0_a165 4096 2017-01-06 11:41 ..
-rw------- 1 u0_a165 u0_a165 4096 2017-01-06 11:51 file__0.localstorage
-rw------- 1 u0_a165 u0_a165    0 2017-01-06 11:51 file__0.localstorage-journal
-rw------- 1 u0_a165 u0_a165 4096 2017-01-06 12:02 http_cdn.myapp.com_0.localstorage
-rw------- 1 u0_a165 u0_a165    0 2017-01-06 12:02 http_cdn.myapp.com_0.localstorage-journal
```

Has anyone solved this issue?

I may try synchronizing the files during the `onPause()` of the activity, but I would like to know if there is a more elegant solution - like consolidated storage.

Comment: There are a couple of problems with sync onPause: 1- Blocking IO task on the Main thread 2- You'd more likely have to merge the two files as opposed to replacing the older file with the newer one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feels a bit *dirty*, but it works (on `KitKat` and newer)!

The `LocalStorageCopier` class below uses a `SharedPreferences` store to keep track of the items (feel free to use whatever else you want instead). **Before** you load the url (local or remote) create an instance of the `LocalStorageCopier` and add it as a `JavascriptInterface` to your webView:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebClient());
storageBackup = new LocalStorageCopier(someContext, someId);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(storageBackup, "backup");
webView.loadUrl (someUrl);
```

**Note:** it is important that the javascript interface is added before loading the page. I was scratching my head as to why "backup is undefined" until I moved this bit to before loading the url (I was adding it just prior to performing the backup).

Now you just have to tie in the *backup* and *restore* actions.

**Backup:** As you mentioned above, the `onPause` method is a good place to back this stuff up. At an appropriate place within your `onPause` add the code below:

```
webView.evaluateJavascript(BACKUP_JAVASCRIPT, new ValueCallback<String>() {
        @Override public void onReceiveValue(String s) {
            LOG.d("Backed up.");
        }
    });
```

where `BACKUP_JAVASCRIPT` is `"(function() { console.log('backing up'); backup.clear(); for (var key in localStorage) { backup.set(key, localStorage.getItem(key)); }})()"`

So now every time your activity is paused, your `localStorage` is backed up.

**Restore** is done in a very similar fashion. You need to initiate the restore action after the page is loaded. This is where the `WebClient` class (code below) comes in. Once the page is done loading, you have to grab all the items in your `LocalStorageCopier` instance and put them in the `localStorage`. The javascript for `RESTORE_JAVASCRIPT` is: `"(function(){console.log('Restoring'); backup.dump(); var len = backup.size(); for (i = 0; i < len; i++) { var key = backup.key(i);  console.log(key); localStorage.setItem(key, backup.get(key));}})()"`

**LocalStorageCopier**

```
public static class LocalStorageCopier {
    private final SharedPreferences store;
    private String[] keys = null;
    private String[] values = null;

    private boolean dumped = false;

    LocalStorageCopier(final Context context, final String id) {
        store = context.getSharedPreferences(id, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public synchronized void dump() {
        if (dumped) throw new IllegalStateException("already dumped");
        final Map<String, ?> map = store.getAll();
        final int size = map.size();
        keys = new String[size];
        values = new String[size];

        int cur = 0;

        for (final String key : map.keySet()) {
            keys[cur] = key;
            values[cur] = (String) map.get(key);
            ++cur;
        }

        dumped = true;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public synchronized int size() {
        if (!dumped) throw new IllegalStateException("dump() first");
        return keys.length;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public synchronized String key(final int i) {
        if (!dumped) throw new IllegalStateException("dump() first");
        return keys[i];
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public synchronized String value(final int i) {
        if (!dumped) throw new IllegalStateException("dump() first");
        return values[i];
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public synchronized String get(final String key) {
        return store.getString(key, null);
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public synchronized void set(final String key, final String value) {
        if (dumped) throw new IllegalStateException("already dumped");
        store.edit().putString(key, value).apply();
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public synchronized void clear() {
        store.edit().clear().apply();
        keys = null;
        values = null;
        dumped = false;
    }

    @Override public synchronized String toString() {
        return store.getAll().toString();
    }
}
```

**WebClient**

```
class WebClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        LOG.d("Page finished. Restoring storage.");

        view.evaluateJavascript(RESTORE_JAVASCRIPT, new ValueCallback<String>() {
            @Override public void onReceiveValue(String s) {
                LOG.d("Restored.");
            }
        });

        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using a symlink, both versions of the webview would use the same file:

[Creating SymLinks in Android](http://androidwarzone.blogspot.ca/2012/03/creating-symbolic-links-on-android-from.html)